# How do I add input a value to a Craft/Twig request?

Tags: templating

This might be a stretch.

How do I (literally) modify the (Tableau API) javascript function below to print a specific fieldName ("Country") so that it can place the "Country" into the CraftCMS/Twig request below?

{% set results = craft.entries.section('posts').search('countryName:"**Value Goes Here**"') %}

[image]

Comment: You can't. The Craft / Twig code runs server-side, _before_ the page is delivered to the browser. The JavaScript runs client side, _after_ the page is delivered to the browser.

Comment: Can you provide that as an answer so you can get credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

The Craft / Twig code runs server-side, before the page is delivered to the browser. The JavaScript runs client side, after the page is delivered to the browser.